How to call snowflake stored procedure in databricks?
I need to call my snowflake procedure in Databricks. How to execute?
Databricks python code for call snowflake stored procedure. I'm getting "unknown function" error when trying this code:
cs.execute("call yourdbname.schemaname.test_proc('value1', 'value2')")


Hi - does the user/role that Databricks is using to connect to Snowflake have the appropriate permissions on the SP?

You just need to establish a connection to snowflake.
You can use the spark connector, jdbc, python connector or snowpark. Once connected just run you call statement
